# CommandAcceptanceException with @ColumnDefault

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss, quarkus

I have schema generation on in the application.properties.

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation.create-schemas=true
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=update
```

So when I'm booting up the app and hibernate tries to generate the tables, I'm getting this error:

```
GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command :
    Error executing DDL "alter table line add constraint FKplr0g1vlmngsgvsj9eskryujs foreign key (id) references task (taskId)"
    via JDBC Statement: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException:
    Error executing DDL "alter table line add constraint FKplr0g1vlmngsgvsj9eskryujs foreign key (id) references task (taskId)"
```

It is an issue while using the [@ColumnDefault](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#annotations-hibernate-columndefault) annotation with a custom Enum called `TaskStatus`. Here is what I have:

```java
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "id-generator")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    @Column
    private UUID taskId;
  
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column
    @ColumnDefault("INCOMPLETE")
    private TaskStatus status;

    ...
}
```

Does anyone know why Hibernate can't create this column default constraint?

UPDATE:

If I initialize the Entity field, the problem is that it will only have that default value for this app, not any other apps that call the db. Whereas if I rely on the column definition to supply a default value, Hibernate seems to be passing a value of null and it overwrites the default value. For now I am solving the issue by using a combination of both solutions:

```java
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(columnDefinition = "enum('INCOMPLETE','QUEUE','ACTIVE','COMPLETE') default 'INCOMPLETE' not null")
private TaskStatus status = TaskStatus.INCOMPLETE;
```

If somebody can explain this behavior I am very interested.

Comment: I have the impression that you must escape the value of `@ColumnDefault`, as if it is used verbatim in the generated SQL statement. So, if `INCOMPLETE` is the name of one of the `TaskStatus` enumeration values (I guess), specify something like `@ColumnDefault("'INCOMPLETE'")`.

Comment: No such luck, it didn't work.